# How are vectors(in C++) having elements of variable size allocated?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, stl

I wrote the following code to accept test-cases on a competetive programming website. It uses a vector `input` of the structure `case` to store the inputs for given test-cases all at once, and then process them one at a time( I have left out the loops that take the input and calculate the output because they are irrelevant to the question.)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

struct case{
    int n, m;
    vector<int> jobsDone;
};

int main(){
    int testCase;
    cin>>testCase;
    vector<case> input;
    input.reserve(testCase); 

    //The rest of the code is supposed to be here
    return 0;
}
```

As I was writing this code, I realised that the working of `input.reserve(t)` in such a case where the element size is variable(since each instance of the structure `case` also has a vector of variable size) would be difficult. Infact, even if I had not explicitly written the `reserve()` statement, the vector still would have reserved a minumum number of elemtns.

For this particular situation, I have the following questions regarding the vector `input`:

- Wouldn't random access in O(1) time be impossible in this case, since the beginning position of every element is not known?
- How would the vector `input` manage element access at all when the beginning location of every element cannot be calculated? Will it pad all the entries to the size of the maximum entry?
- Should I rather be implementing `cases` using a vector of pointers pointing to each instance of `case`? I am thinking about this because if the vector pads each element to a size and wastes space, or it maintains the location to each element, and random access is not constant in time, hence there is no use for a vector anyway.

Comment: A vector is simply a pointer to some memory plus some more information. But the size of this pointer plus additional information is constant. The size of memory it is pointing to is varying of course, but this is irrelevant to the size of `input` itself.

Comment: Why do you think "the beginning position of every element is not known"? `sizeof(vector<int>)` always has the exact same value, and therefore so does `sizeof(case)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every object type has a fixed size. This is what `sizeof` returns. A `vector` itself typically holds a pointer to the array of objects, the number of objects for which space has been allocated, and the number of objects actually contained. The size of these three things is independent of the number of elements in the vector.

For example, a `vector<int>` might contain:
1) An `int *` holding the address of the data.
2) A `size_t` holding the number of objects we've allocated space for
3) A `size_t` holding the number of objects contained in the vector.

This will probably be somewhere around 24 bytes, regardless of how many objects are in the vector. And this is what `sizeof(vector<int>)` will return.

Comment: most vectors are implemented using 3 pointers. implementation detail ofc.